# How to add a parallax effect to divs that contain an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, parallax

I have a 6 Vimeo iframes all within their own divs. I want to add a parallax effect to them so each video scrolls over the other. So in reverse order - the 6th video will scroll over the 5th, the 5th over the 4th, and so on- until over the 1st video.

I am using this code that works with an image, but I cannot get it to work on divs.

```
    <script>
    var yPos, vid;
    function parallax () {
        yPos = window.pageYOffset;
        vid = document.getElementsByClassName("vid2")
        vid.style.top = yPos * 0.4 + "px";

    }

window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax); 
    </script>
```

Below is the rest of the code.

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<style>
html {

    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: lato,  sans-serif;
    text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    margin:0;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    /*background-color: grey;*/
}
#about {

}
            /*This section isfor the header section that includes the header itself, my h1 text logo, the nav bar and the top social buttons*/

#offset {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index:9999;
}
#progressBar {
    background-color: black;
    height: 7px;
    width:0;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    max-width:100%;
    z-index:20001;
}


header {
    /*background-color: hsla(359,70%,46%,1.00);*/
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0%;
    z-index: 20000;

}

            /*This h1 is in the header section and the h1 has an ID=logo and is in 2 sections, id=bgdr and id=creative.*/

h1 {
    /*background-color: orange;*/
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: justify;
    color: black;
    position: fixed;
    left: 40px;
    top:0px;
}


#logo {
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 4.em;
    font-weight:100;
    text-align: justify;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;


}

            /*#bgdr and #creative IDs are part of the h1 (#logo). They are in 2 IDs so that I can adjust the BGDR and creative text independantly*/

#bgdr {
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight:100;
}

#creative {
    font-size: 0.6em;
    text-align: justify;
    letter-spacing: 0.28em;
    padding-left: 4px;
    font-weight:100;
}   

            /* the "a" selector is followed by "link, visited and hover" to animate the states of menu/text links throughout the page/site*/

a:link {
    color: hsla(0,0%,0%,1.00);
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: color 0.5s;
    transition: color 0.5s;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:300;
}

a:visited {
    color: hsla(0,0%,0%,1.00);
}

a:hover {
    color: hsla(0,0%,72%,1.00);
}

a:active {
    font-weight: 800;
}


            /*the ul, li, and .nav control the top nav menu. The ul is the table, il are the cells. (front page, about, contact, etc.)*/

ul {
    /*background-color: blue;*/

    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    top:75px;
    right:30px;
    padding: 0em;
    font-size: 1.15em;
    float: right;
}

 li {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    width: inherit;
    margin-left: 3em;
}

            /*This is a class for my social buttons that are just below the menu (not large buttons at the bottom of the page*/
.social {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 11em;
    right: 30px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    top: 170px;
}

            /*h2=page name e.g. About h3=Sound/music/web h4=long version*/
h2, h3, h4  {
            text-align: center; 
}   

            /*h2 is the title of each page eg "ABOUT"*/

h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
    position: relative;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 200;
    top: -40px;
}

h2 #homeH2 {
    position:relative;
    top: 200px;
}


h4 {
    font-weight:300; 
    font-size:1.4em
}

h2+p {
    text-align:center;
} 

    /*web text*/
p {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight:300;
}

main {
    position: relative;
    top: 240px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -5em;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;

    padding-bottom: 5px;
}




footer {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width: 415px;
    left:35%;
    top: 325%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text">



       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title >BGDR creative</title>
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.--><script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<!--The following script tag downloads a font from the Adobe Edge Web Fonts server for use within the web page. We recommend that you do not modify it.-->
<!--<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>-->
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/lato:n1,i1,n3,i3,n4,i4,n7,i7,n9,i9:all.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

</head>
<div id="progressBar" data-0="width: 0%" data-end="width: 100%" ></div>
<div id="offset">10</div> 
<body id="about">

<header>


  <!-- h1 is a text logo (i need to check to see having a h1 text logo is ok)-->

        <h1 id="logo" role="button"> 
            <a href="../../Dreamweaver /Pages/Home.html" title="Back to the front page" role="link">
                <span id="bgdr">
                    BGDR
                </span>
                    <br>
                <span id="creative">
                    creative
                </span>
            </a>
        </h1>

         <!-- navigation menu-->        
  <nav id="nav" role="navigation" align="right">

                <ul>
                <li><a href="Contact.html" title="Contact Me" rel="next">CONTACT        </a>    </li>
                <li><a href="Blog.html" title="A blog of my work and musings" rel="next">BLOG   </a>    </li>
                <li><a href="CV.html" title="CV" rel="next">CV                      </a>    </li>
                <li><a href="Visual.html" title="Film and Animation" rel="next">VISUAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="Sound.html" title="Sound" rel="next">SOUND                         </a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html" title="About BGDR" rel="next">ABOUT            </a>    </li>
                <li ><a href="Home.html" title="Go Home" rel="next">FRONT PAGE      </a>    </li>
                </ul>
                </nav>  
                <br>



</header>

        <!--Below is the "main" content of the page, which includes the about section-->
<main role="main">

<section role="application">
<h3 class="centerText">Moving Image</h3>
<p class="centerText">These videos are all graphics and film that I created or helped create.</p>

<div class="vid1">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/137215594?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="vid2">  
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/136115302?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="vid3">  
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/136065794?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="vid4">
   <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/134271788?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="vid5">   
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/98621690?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="vid6">
   <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/136049986?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

</section>

</main>



        <footer role="contentinfo">



        </footer>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/skrollr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var s = skrollr.init({
        render: function(data) {
            //Log the current scroll position.
            //console.log(data.curTop);
            $("#offset").text(data.curTop);
        }
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    var yPos, vid;
    function parallax () {
        yPos = window.pageYOffset;
        vid = document.getElementsByClassName("vid2")
        vid.style.top = yPos * 0.4 + "px";

    }

window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax); 
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't set `style` on an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), you need to loop over them.

Comment: Forgive me. I am relatively new to web development. I am not sure what you mean. I did not use an HTMLCollection @AlexanderO'Mara.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("vid2")` returns an `HTMLCollection`. Presumably you want to loop over the elements inside the collection, to set the `style`.